# Using chain rule to prove the Implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, chain-rule

In Analysis 2 by Terence Tao, the **Implicit function theorem** is stated as follow:

> Let $E$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Let $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable.
> Let $y = (y_1, y_2, .., y_n)$ be a point in $E$ such that $f(y) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} (y) \neq 0$.
> Then:
> $\color{red}{(1)}$. There exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R^{n-1}}$ containing the point $(y_1,..,y_{n-1})$ and an open subset $V$ of $E$ containing the point $y$ and a function $g: U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:
> +) $g(y_1,..,y_{n-1}) = y_n \qquad$ and
> +) The set  {$(x_1, x_2,..,x_n) \in V$ : $f(x_1,...,x_n) = 0 $} = {$(x_1,..,x_{n-1}, g(x_1,..,x_{n-1})$ : $(x_1,x_2,..,x_{n-1}) \in U$ }
> $\color{red}{(2)}$. Function $g$ is differentiable at the point $(y_1, y_2, ..., y_{n-1})$
> $\color{red}{(3)}$. We have $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j} (y_1,..,y_{n-1})$ = $- \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(y) / \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(y)$  $\qquad$ for all $1 <= j <= n-1$

I have understood the author's proof of the point $(1)$ and $(2)$ but don't know how to use the chain rule (which relates to total derivative), differentiating in $x_j$ (as suggested by the author) to prove (3).

> **Theorem 6.4.1 (Several variable calculus chain rule)**
> Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, and let $F$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R^m}$. Let $f : E \to F$ be a function, and let $g : F \to \mathbb{R^p}$ be another function. Let $x_0$ be a point in the interior of $E$.
> Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, and that $f(x_0)$ is in the interior of $F$ . Suppose also that $g$ is differentiable at $f(x_0)$.
> Then $g ◦ f : E \to \mathbb{R^p}$ is also differentiable at $x_0$, and we have the formula:
> $(g◦f)'(x_0) = g'(f(x_0)) f'(x_0)$

Could you please give a sketch of a proof of point (3) using the chain rule ?

**EDIT**:
As stated by the author, what we want is to have the equation:

> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(y)$ + $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(y). \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j} (y_1,..,y_{n-1}) $ $= 0$

Comment: In the chain rule $(g \circ f)'(x_0) = g'(f(x_0)) f'(x_0)$, are $g'$ and $f'$ total derivatives?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz: yes, if there is a partial derivative, there will be the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ notation!

Comment: It might be easier for you to use the formula involving partial derivatives (usually called the chain rule, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case)) instead of the formula involving total derivatives. Just apply it to the function $f(x_1,..,x_{n-1}, g(x_1,..,x_{n-1}))$ (which is identically zero, by the way).

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?
Can you write down the proof?